# Integrating Progress bar with todo list app

Tags: android-studio, progress-bar

I have found a small Todo application and it is very simple and i'm using it to practice. User enters title description and time then the task will be automatically set to not completed until he or she update it as completed.

The challenge is how i can add a progress bar to this to give the result of completed tasks which the user entered against the incomplete ones.

Example this simple application : https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-room-database-example/

Comment: Rather then linking the code/app, you should add some code examples and tell us what you are stuck with, We won't write code for you and we certainly can't help you with a code problem is we don't know what your code looks like.

Comment: Hi,
thank you for your comment.
i'm not expecting anyone to write a code what i'm looking for is a concept or an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to answer your question without specific code to look at but it seems like if you want to create a progress bar you can refer to this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.

If you have a function that calculates how much progress you have made, you can update your progress bar by using the setProgress() function. So every time your user has completed a task, you have your int progress variable increase by 1. If your user enters another task, you can also just increase the Max value by using the setMax() function.

Your question is a bit vague but I hope that this helped.

Comment: Hi Louis,
thank you for your reply. this is what i was looking for and really thank you. 
apologies if my question was not explained well and supported with codes.